# Can we hold more than 2 data types in a STL list?

Tags: list, stl

I mean if we use struct .. we can use as many as data types we want in a list.!!
For Example:

```
struct{
  string name;
  int number;
  string CompanyName;
  int age;
};
```

is it possible to hold more than 2 data types in a STL list.

Answer (score 0):

A STL container (search for posts here about why we don't call it STL anymore) like `list` contains elements of a single type. Not two. Not six. One type.

However, as you point out, you can define your own type to be the elements of the list.  Also, the standard library (as of C++17) contains a template named `variant`, which can contain one of a set of types.